# Yarn: How to link acorn using boltpkg - symlink error

Tags: symlink, yarnpkg, bolt

My team has a monorepo where we are using [bolt](https://github.com/boltpkg/bolt) to manage dependencies and linking. I was trying to get the dev environment up and running on my local Windows machine but had issues install/link `acorn`. What I did was clone the repo, then `$ bolt` to install dependencies. As you can see, it showed error linking dependencies and complained about `acorn.ps1` not being a symlink. I've done some research but **none** of the solutions I found, such as including `--non-bin-links` or running as admin, worked for me. I'd appreciate if you could provide some insights on this.

- Windows: 10;
- Yarn: 1.13.0;
- Bolt: 0.22.6 - tried 0.22.4 as well but did not work;

[image: error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution to this issue.

`acorn` is not a dependency for my project, but it is one for `yarn` itself, as I searched for it and it only appears in `yarn.lock`. Meaning there's definitely something weird with my current version of Yarn, `1.13.0`. So I downgraded it to `1.12.3` and according to the official documentation, installed `bolt` as a local package instead of a global one. It solved this issue.